# How to Convert Bit String to Boolean Array

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net, boolean, dayofweek

In VB or C#, is there a concise way (no looping) to convert a string to a boolean array? I have a string of binary values representing days of the week ("0001100") and wish to convert to a boolean array (false, false, false, true, true, false, false).

Comment: Why so scared of looping?

Comment: Why so scared of concise solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no built in method for turning a string into a boolean array.

You have to do that by looping the characters in the string and check each one for the value, but you can easily do that with the `Select` method:

```
bool[] days = daysString.Select(c => c == '1').ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to simply convert:

```
"0001100".Select(c => c == '1').ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

VB versions

```
Dim dayStr As String = "0001100"

Dim daysB() As Boolean
'using LINQ
daysB = dayStr.Select(Function(ch) ch = "1").ToArray

'using loop
Dim daysB1(dayStr.Length - 1) As Boolean

For idx As Integer = 0 To dayStr.Length - 1
    daysB1(idx) = dayStr(idx) = "1"
Next
```